# D3.js collapsible tree - expand/collapse intermediate nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a D3.js [collapsible tree](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) which has a bunch of nodes. There are a few paths in the tree in which there sequences of nodes with only one child. Imagine this tree:

```
               5
              /
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 -6
              \
               7
```

When the `1` node is clicked, I want it to become:

```
      5
     /
1 - 4 -6
     \
      7
```

Right now my code expands and collapses nodes normally. How can I select those *intermediate* nodes so I can target them with my toggle function as I do right now?

My code is basically the same as in the example, except for some stuff I added that isn't related to this question. The `toggle()` function receives a pointer to a `node` and makes the visible child nodes (in the `children` array) invisible (by moving them to them `_children` array). This hits *all* the children (and grandchildren, and great-grandchildren,...) to that specific node, but I need it to continue while it finds nodes with *exactly* 1 child, then, if it finds a node that has no children, I want it to be visible; if the node has more than 1 child, I want it to show all of them from that point on.

This is the `toggle()` function code that is called onclick in one of the nodes:

```
function toggle(d) {
    var myLength;
    if(d.children){myLength = d.children.length;}
    else{myLength=0;}

    if (myLength === 1) {
        //next will be the first node we find with more than one child
        var next = d.children[0];
        for (;;) {if(next.hasOwnProperty('children')){
            if (next.children.length === 1) {
                next = next.children[0];
            } else if (next.children.length > 1) {
                break;
                }
            } else {
                // you'll have to handle nodes with no children
                break;
            }
        }
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = [next];
    }else{
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That toggle function doesn't do any sort of logic checking, it simply removes and adds the children. To do what you want, you'll need to use a bit of logic and data traversing, but it's not impossible. Try something like this:

```
function toggle(d) {
    if (d.children.length === 1) {
        //next will be the first node we find with more than one child
        var next = d.children[0];
        for (;;) {
            if (next.children.length === 1) {
                next = next.children[0];
            } else if (next.children.length > 1) {
                break;
            } else {
                //you'll have to handle nodes with no children
            }
        }

        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = [next];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The childless nodes don't actually need any specific behaviour - ie, they aren't _toggable_. This mostly works, except for the reverse operation - when I click an collapsed sequence - it does not expand again. Also, if the sequence ends in a childless node, I can't collapse it either. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh! And the nodes that have more than 1 child aren't collapsible anymore, either.. :S

Comment: I have tweaked around your example and now, the nodes that have more than 1 child behave like they supposed to. The nodes in a sequence of single-child nodes collapse, but don't expand. If the sequence ends in a childless node, it does not collapse/expand. Check my updated code above.

Comment: Figured it out regarding the sequence ending in a childless node with the `next.hasOwnProperty` bit. Now just need to make it revert as well. Care to help?

Comment: I swear these comment notifications never showed up in my inbox. Sorry about that. If you're still having trouble, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleChildren(d) {

    var myLength;

    if (d.toggle !== "close") {
        if(d.children){
            myLength = d.children.length;
        }else{
            myLength=0;
        }
        d._children = d.children;
        if (myLength === 1){
            //next will be the first node we find with more than one child
            var next = d.children[0];
            for (;;) {if(next.hasOwnProperty('children')){
                if (next.children.length === 1) {
                    next = next.children[0];
                } else if (next.children.length > 1) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                // you'll have to handle nodes with no children
                break;
            }
            }
            d.children = [next];
            //d._children = d.children;
            d.toggle = "close"
        }else{
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(d.toggle == "close"){
            var _children = d.children;
            d.children  = d._children;
            d._children =   _children;
            d.toggle = "open"
        }else{
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
        }

    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a little more insight in to your solution?